# How to get recent app's snapshot?

Tags: android, task

I started to buil a task switching app , I've learned how to get active apps icon and app name ,but can not find anything how to get recent apps thumbnail . 
Like this Example: 
http://www.androidguys.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/recent-apps1.png

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 view.buildDrawingCache();
 Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
```

to get images of your views and show them as you need